# Connecting MS Access database when another application using the same MS Access File

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access, silverlight-4.0

I'm having Silverlight with the c# application which connects to ms access database in the server. My connection string looks like,

```
  Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=\\151.12.1.99\DatabasePath\Database.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=Password;Mode= Read
```

It works fine when I execute the application directly without any error. But when I deploy the application it throws

```
 "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file "\\151.12.1.99\DatabasePath\Database.mdb". It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.
```

Can any help me what is the problem? I'm opening the file in reading mode only.

Comment: Do you have write permissions on the folder where the mdb file is stored as even though you are opening read only, it needs to create/edit a lock file (.ldb)?

Comment: Yes I have write permission for the folder. When I execute through code i dont have any issue. The error comes only deploy and run the application. (Note: When I refer to that folder already an .lbl file presents which represents the file is already open. But I want to just select some data thats it.

Comment: "An ldb file is already present", it sounds as though whatever has the file open already may have it opened in exclusive mode.  As a side note, you're not using a secuirty (mdw) file are you, if so when using the deployed copy are you still making use of the relevant security file?

Comment: Even if the database is not used by any other application I get the same error. i.e. No user is using the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use a DSN instead ???

The problem is that once your app opens the .mdb file it stays "reserved" to that instance of the app. The easyest way arround this I think is to use a DSN, to let ODBC manage the database access.

```
conn.ConnectionString = "FIL=MS Access;DSN=your_dsn_name";
```

Comment: saranya: if the file format is .mdb then when you open the file it creates a temp file, that will be deleted when the connection to the .mdb file is properly closed. For example, if an exception is throwed and not dealt with, the temp file will stay in the filesystem, preventing you from opening the .mdb file. Either you delete the temp file while debuging or you use try ... catch to deal with that task for you.

Comment: Thank you the feedback Antonio. I tried the dsn connection it works fine when execute direct through visual studio. But when I publish it gives to error [HY024] is there anything i have to set permission for IIS.

Comment: saranya: check your permissions on the folder where the database is stored. The HY024 error is common when you dont have permissions to access the folder where the file is stored. It can also be a missconfiguration of the DNS, if you have it configured to use "Windows Authentication" it will work just fine in the local machine or in any machines inside the same Windows Domain, but outside your "user" that will be "guest", does not have the same permissions to access the folder.

Comment: My database present in different domain and I want to access from different domain. Is there any possibility to connect between cross domains

Comment: If the Domains "Trust" each other, it should work, check if the Domain Controllers trust each other and the firewall allows network trafic between them.

You should be able to configure the autentication method of the DSN, there you may use an user account that is valid on the other domain using "user@domain.yourdomain" and a valid password for that user, with permissions to access the folder where the file is located.